Query table based on table_name from information_schema in Databricks SQL
I have one table that changes the name every 60 days. The name simple increases the number version, for example:

First 60 days: table_name_v1. After 60 days: table_name_v2 and so on.

What I want is to query the table which name returned in the query of information_schema using just SQL in Databricks SQL. This is important because I have a Databricks SQL Dashboard and when the name changes, I won't need to adapt the query name.
Here is a example of what I want.
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP VIEW db_copart AS

SELECT
    table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE
    table_schema = 'table_sandbox'
    and table_name ILIKE '%db_pi_copart_v%'; -- this will return the latest table version

SELECT
        *
FROM table_sandbox.(select table_name from db_copart)

